# How can I understand when llvm changed signature to function

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I have C code like this:

```
typedef struct {
  int a1;
  double a2;
} str3;
...
extern void someVoidFunc(int a);
extern str3 someStrFunc(int b);
int main() {
  someVoidFunc(0);
  someStrFunc(0);
  return 0;
}
```

In llvm represatation this looks like:

```
%struct.str3 = type { i32, double}
...
call void @someVoidFunc(i32 0)
call void @someStrFunc(%struct.str3* sret %tmp, i32 0)
...
```

So, I didn't understand, why llvm change signature, and how can I understand which type really return function?

Comment: I assume this is `llvm`'s (`clang`'s?) way of implementing [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: I compile C file (to bitecode) with -O0 option (yes, through clang)

Comment: I think you'd have to dig though the Clang code to figure this out for sure, but it could be that returning class types this way is so fundamental to the way `clang` compiles that even `-O0` won't turn it off

Comment: maybe do you know how disable RVO in `clang`?

Comment: p.s.RVO can not be disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs passed by value to functions and returned by value are **tricky**. They are tricky because they require very specific rules on how the compiler translates them to assembly (the platform ABI). While LLVM tries to remain platform independent, C is very much platform dependent in this respect, and so Clang does the ABI-specific lowering of structs passed by value and structs returned by value, so that the subsequent LLVM IR --> native code lowering *just works*.

**TL;DR:** you've picked a very nasty corner to explore. If you really care about such function signatures, then start by going through the AMD64 ABI (or ARM ABI) looking at the rules for passing structs through registers. If you don't really care about these specific use cases, then find some simpler examples to play with.

Answer (score -2):

So, how said @Collin this is RVO.
We can understand when llvm changed signature to function by attribute [sret](http://llvm.org/releases/3.2/docs/LangRef.html#paramattrs).
In code we're could detect this using method [hasStructRetAttr](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Argument.html)

Comment: It's not an RVO. RVO is completely different thing from C++ world. Eli's correct here.